# Database design for Group Supervision

Tags: mysql

I am currently having an issue with my database that requires supervisors to monitor a group with students in the group.

- Entites: Student, Supervisor and Group
- A Student can only be in one group but the group can have many students
- A Group can have only one Supervisor but Supervisors can have Many Groups

I hope this Image will explain more:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Bye.

Comment: StudentID should be removed from Group table and GroupID should be added to the Students table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here how it is supposed to be according to your data model explained.
As explained, removed StudentID from Groups and added GroupID into Students since Groups can have MANY students but Student can be assigned to only ONE group.
SupervisorID should stay in Groups since Groups can have only ONE Supervisor.

[image: Here how it is supposed to be according to 1-2-3]